# How do I use SRFI-1 in Guile?

Tags: scheme, guile

I am trying to use srfi-1 in guile. I used the following code to include the srfi:
`(use-modules (srfi srfi-1))`

However, I get an error saying that srfi is probably undefined. How should I used srfi?

I tried googling this problem, but it seems that I am the first person with this problem.

Comment: It works for me with Guile 2.0.11. What version of Guile are you using?

Comment: I've posted an answer in the module case. But if you're actually writing a standalone program, make sure that the `use-modules` is at the top level, and isn't misspelt (e.g., as `use-module` or the like).

Comment: I am writing a standalone program. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`(use-modules (srfi srfi-1))` is indeed the correct way to import SRFI 1, in top-level programs and in the REPL.

However, based on your previous question, I believe you may actually be writing a module instead, in which case the syntax is a little different. You'd use `#:use-module (srfi srfi-1)` inside your `define-module`. Example:

```
(define-module (my module)
  #:use-module (srfi srfi-1)
  ;; rest of the module declaration here
  )
```